# Rewrite url of website to

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I wanted ask you what command has to be written in the .htaccess to achieve my domain to look like

like this website

It's files are stored in 
http://imgah.com/ but it shows http://imgah.com/_ as the url.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming since your talking about URL Rewriting that your server has Apaches mod_rewrite module installed, you can put this rewrite rule in a .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^_(.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which would mean, `/_` would rewrite to `/` , `/_index.html` would rewrite to `/index.html` and so on.

There's a whole site dedicated to Mod Rewrite here: http://www.modrewrite.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively just use mod_alias to do the exact same thing:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/_(.*)$ /$1
```

This will change the URL address bar of the browser so that the underscore is removed.